# Polymer 1.x unit testing spy not getting called

Tags: unit-testing, polymer-1.0, sinon, chai

I have a piece of code which is doing some DOM manipulation calling functions like appendChild and RemoveChild.

so, say my component has a div tag with id property

```
    <div id="header"></div>
```

Inside my component in one of the functions I am getting hold of the mentioned tag and appending something

```
   this.$.header.appendChild('<div>Hello</div>')
```

In my unit test I create test fixture with the responsible component and then inside I create a spy like

```
   var testSpy = sinon.spy(Polymer.dom($el.$.header), 'appendChild')
```

this is done inside my setup. And then inside my it block I check for the spy to be called. But it not getting called. Though the appendChild is being called and I could see the dom correctly as well. But in the expect it is not working. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to figure it out on my own. The only different thing which I did was the way I was getting hold of my DOM while creating the spy:

```
var testSpy = sinon.spy($el.querySelector('#header'), 'appendChild')
```

After that my spy started to be called.